# netsh, block all IP addresses in a text file?

Tags: windows, firewall, windows-firewall, netsh

Is there a way for me to import a `.txt` file (with IP addresses on each line) into Windows Firewall?

I want each of the IP addresses to be completely blocked. That would also provide an easy way to unblock an IP address in the `.txt` file later on (in combination with `netsh`).

I am currently using Peerblock but it tends to cause some load on the CPU sometimes.

Comment: I think you should be able to do this with powershell...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

Save this as `blockit.bat`:

```
@echo off
if "%1"=="list" (
  netsh advfirewall firewall show rule Blockit | findstr RemoteIP
  exit/b
)

:: Deleting existing block on ips
netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name="Blockit"

:: Block new ips (while reading them from blockit.txt)
for /f %%i in (blockit.txt) do (
  netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Blockit" protocol=any dir=in action=block remoteip=%%i
  netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Blockit" protocol=any dir=out action=block remoteip=%%i
)

:: call this batch again with list to show the blocked IPs
call %0 list
```

Create a `blockit.txt` with your IPs to block and run `blockit`.

You can run `blockit list` to check which IPs are blocked at the moment.

Note: This needs to be run as Administrator.

Edit: Didn't know if you wanted outgoing or incoming traffic blocked so i added both `dir=in` and `dir=out`. You can delete one or the other (or leave them both for both directions).